# Java failing to access this method?

Tags: java

I am fairly new java programmer and I need a bit of help. So there is a problem I have with accessing non-static variables from another class. So what I am trying to do is use this:

```
public void Snowba_Method(int num, Player player) {
    new Snowba_Main().playerSpawn(num, player);
}
```

In a class that doesn't contain the variable i need to access, and i use Snowba_Method(num, player); To access it. But when that happends, it doesn't seem to reach this bit of code:

```
    public void playerSpawn(int num, Player player) {
        player.sendMessage("test");
        Location tpPos = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(getConfig().getString("iGSpawnPos.SpawnWorld" + num))
                , getConfig().getInt("iGSpawnPos.SpawnX" + num)
                , getConfig().getInt("iGSpawnPos.SpawnY" + num)
                , getConfig().getInt("iGSpawnPos.SpawnZ" + num));
        player.teleport(tpPos);
    }
```

Now, I am using a custom jar, and I have tested everything. I've narrowed it down to this bit. I don't understand why this doesn't work.

```js
public void Snowba_Method(int num, Player player) {
    new Snowba_Main().playerSpawn(num, player);
} // It seems to stop here.
```

Comment: What is the output of the program? Do you have any exception?

Comment: *But when that happends, it doesn't seem to reach this bit of code* How did you verify, that this bit of code is not accessed? If the method seems to "stop" at the line you marked, I would guess that there is some kind of endless loop.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what's happening if you don't put those methods in the context of a class. Where is the declaration of Snowba_Main()?

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem to reach" mean? Have you executed this code with your debugger, line by line? Have you added traces in the code to see what happens? What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Is there any exception being logged?

Comment: I'm fairly new at java, and i don't understand how to declare snowba_main.

Comment: Also, i might add that this is a minecraft plugin.

Comment: Your code new Snowba_Main() creates a new instance of the class Snowba_Main using the default constructor. Did you write this class?

Comment: I had the class previously.

Comment: The strange thing is, when i use the new method on other classes, it seems to work.

Comment: I would bet that you didn't register that method to be an event handler

Comment: Do i need to use @EventHandler?

Comment: http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference says: yes. However I am no Minecraft modder

Comment: Wait, that is a method... It shouldn't be listening to anything, only telling the other function to work

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger?

Answer (score -1):

> accessing non-static variables from another class

Is usually solved by a getter on the object. (Non-static variables can only exist in objects).